# MAC - STS 4 "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine"

Tags: java, macos

After installing STS 4 I'm getting below message: 
[MAC - STS 4 "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHLKl.png) 
...

SpringToolSuite4.ini:

```
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.1100.v20190907-0426
-product
org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/sts4.icns
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Java Version:

```
java version "14" 2020-03-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)
```

$JAVA_HOME:
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. And it has been solved on my mac

step1. rename libjli.dylib

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/MacOS
sudo mv libjli.dylib libjli.dylib.bak
```

step2. create linked file for libjli.dylib

```
sudo ln -s ../Home/lib/libjli.dylib libjli.dylib
```

step3. restart Eclipse.

This should be a bug for Eclipse and should be fixed in the next version of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, It has been fixed with the latest version of Eclipse